# Populating ExpandableListView from database - not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite, expandablelistview

I have tables Receipt and Logs and table receipt has_many logs. So on my LogsRecapitulation.class I have grouping logs by sort and grade(those two columns are from table logs).

I have trying to made this via ExpandableListView. Each group of logs parent elements will consists of Sort and Grade for each group from database.

Children elements will have textViews for logs count in child element, mass, price and some calculated price. And it should look something like this:

[image]

I have created expandableListView layouts and adapter. But now I have trouble with populating parent and child elements from database.

Here is my code so you can see  what I have done so far.

This is expandableListAadapter class:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listDataChild;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expendable_items, null);
        }

        TextView logsMass = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exp_lis_mass);
        TextView logsPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exp_lis_price);
        TextView logsMassPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ext_lis_sum_price);
        logsMass.setText(childText);
        logsPrice.setText(childText);
        logsMassPrice.setText(childText);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_group, null);
        }

        TextView logsSort = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exp_gr_sort);
        TextView logsGrade = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exp_gr_grade);
        TextView logsCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exp_gr_logs_count);
        logsSort.setText(headerTitle);
        logsGrade.setText(headerTitle);
        logsCount.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is my logsRecapitulation class:

```
public class LogsRecapitulation extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.expandable_layout);
        //recieve RecepitID and query to group_by logs
        final long forwardedId = (long) getIntent().getExtras().get(String.valueOf("recepitID"));
        List<Logs> logsList = new Select().from(Logs.class).where("Receipt = " + forwardedId).groupBy("SortID, Grade").execute();
        //get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        prepareListData();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    private void prepareListData() {

    }
}
```

My problem now is to populate ExpendableListView with data from database. Here are my table classes:

```
//receipt table
@Table(name = "Receipt")
public class Receipt extends Model {
    @Column(name="Place")
    String place;
    @Column(name="ShippingNumber")
    String shippingNumber;
    @Column(name="Warehouse")
    String warehouse;
    @Column(name="Carrier")
    String carrier;
    @Column(name="LicencePlate")
    String licencePlate;
    @Column(name = "Driver")
    String driver;
    @Column(name = "Customer")
    String customer;
    @Column(name= "DestWarehouse")
    String destWarehouse;
    @Column(name = "Employee")
    String employee;
    @Column(name = "PriceType")
    String priceType;
    @Column(name = "PriceCorrection")
    Double priceCorrection;
    @Column(name = "PriceCorrection2")
    Double priceCorrection2;
    @Column(name = "Supplier")
    String supplier;
    @Column(name = "CreatedAt")
    Date createdAt;
}
//logs table
@Table(name = "Logs")
public class Logs extends Model {
    @Column(name="PlateNumber")
    String plate_number;
    @Column(name="SortID")
    String sort_id;
    @Column(name="Grade")
    String grade;
    @Column(name = "Diametar")
    double diameter;
    @Column(name="Length")
    double length;
    @Column(name="CreatedAt")
    Date createdAt;
    @Column(name="Receipt")
    Receipt receipt;
    @Column(name = "Price")
    Price price;
}
//price table
@Table(name = "Price")
public class Price extends Model {
    @Column(name = "Sort")
    String sort;
    @Column(name = "Grade")
    String grade;
    @Column(name = "Diameter")
    double diameter;
    @Column(name = "LengthDG")
    double lengthDG;
    @Column(name = "LengthGG")
    double lengthGG;
    @Column(name = "StumpPriceKn")
    double stumpPrice_kn;
    @Column(name = "RoadPriceKn")
    double roadPrice_kn;
}
```

Note: I'm using ActiveAndroid.

Please if anyone knows how to populate expandable listView from database please help.

**Question: What should I do to successfully populate ExpandableListView from database?**